# PHP Symfony - Provide credentials only to owner of object

Tags: php, security, symfony1

I am trying to wrap my head around symfony's user authentication. Need advice on **best practices**.

*apps/frontend/modules/mymodule/config/security.yml*

```
edit:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: owner

all:
  is_secure: false
```

When and where do I set `$this->getUser()->addCredential('owner')`?
In a filter of the filter chain?

If I set it there, when do I remove the credentials again?
I could just remove in the same filter, if the user is not the owner of that object, but then once the user edited one object, he will have the owner credentials, until he tries to edit something he doesn't own. Is there a drawback to that?

Or is there a way to set the needed credentials to the id of the object? Like

```
edit:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: %%request_id%%
```

And then add user credentials on login for all their ids?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

---

**Update 1:**

Would something like this work? Can't test right now if the code actually works. ***Would this be best practice***?

*apps/frontend/config/filters.yml*

```
// ...

security:
  class: addOwnerCredentials

// ...
```

*apps/frontend/lib/addOwnerCredentials.class.php*

```
class addOwnerCredentials extends sfBasicSecurityFilter
{

  function execute($filterChain)
  {
    $context = $this->getContext();
    $request = $context->getRequest();
    $user = $context->getUser();

    $user_ids = $user->getAllOwnership();

    // Add owner credential for current user or remove if he has it but shouldn't
    if (in_array($request->getParameter('id'), $user_ids)) {
      $user->addCredential('owner');
    }
    elseif ($user->hasCredential('owner')) {
      $user->removeCredential('owner');
    }

    // Continue down normal filterChain
    parent::execute($filterChain);

    // On the way back, before rendering, remove owner credential again
    // The code after the call to $filterChain->execute() executes after the
    // action execution and before the rendering.
    if ($user->hasCredential('owner')) {
      $user->removeCredential('owner');
    }
  }

}
```

---

**Update 2:**
Added to code snippet, to remove the owner credentials, right after they were needed, so the user doesn't have a unnecessary credential in their session.

Comment: I know I could just check the user_id of the object against the user's id in the executeEdit method, but that seems like a workaround. Looking for best practice.

Comment: I've done a similar thing by over-riding the hasCredential method to call an isOwnedBy method on the request object, passing it the current user. Classes with a user_id field are handled automatically via a method in a parent class. This is over-ridden for more complicated checks.

Comment: _"Classes with a user_id field are handled automatically via a method in a parent class"_ Is that your implementation or does symfony do that automagically? Where can I read up on that if it is a symfony feature? And I couldn't find the hasCredential() method. Where is it defined? Tried sfWebRequest and sfRequest. Anyways, I feel like my approach is a bit _'cleaner'_. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Its a method I've added. The hasCredential method is in the sfUser class... same method as you are calling in your code!

Comment: Ohhhh! Now I get you! Must've hit my head too hard when I was a kid or something ;) Thanks for your approach. Will try and see if I like it better than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put my custom filter which adds arbitrary credentials to user *before* security filter, not replaced them. This looks like only difference between our approaches :)

So, I'd say yes, it (I mean UPD1) *is* best practice.

Comment: I just felt like it belonged to security, because it does security checks ;) Thanks for your answer, will leave question open for a bit, and see if there are more opinions.

Comment: PS: I don't _replace_ the filter, I am extending it `class addOwnerCredentials extends sfBasicSecurityFilter`

Comment: I see your point. But if you'll ever want to enhance security filter, you will have to reimplement its' functionality in `addOwnerCredentials` filter class.

Comment: If I ever write a sfAdvancedSecurityFilter, that extends sfBasicSecurityFilter, I will have to change my addOwnerCredentials to extend the advanced filter, that's true. Thanks for input.